# How do I assign type when using forEach in Typescript(Object of type unknown)

Tags: typescript

```
let payload = {
  item1: ["value1", "value2", "value3"],
  item2: [],
  item3: ["value4", "value5"]
}

Object.entries(payload).forEach(([key, values]) => {
if (values.length === 0) {
    // do this stuff
```

I'm getting an error that values is of type unknown. I'm not sure how to give it a type of array.

key will always be a string, and values will always be an array of strings.

Comment: Can you add a sample payload?

Comment: Good question, edited payload

Comment: interface Payload {
  item1: any;
  item2: any;
item3: any
} then, payload: Payload []

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. The items I get is random since its from an API call, how do i not hardcode it to 3 items? and I would just put string[] for an array of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify type of the key in an interface, so you wont be limited to a number.

```
interface Payload{
    [key: string]: string[];
}

const payload: Payload = {
    a: ['foo', 'bar'],
    b: [],
    c: ['baz']
};
Object.keys(payload).forEach((key, idx) => {
    if (payload[key].length === 0) {
    // do the stuff
}
});
```

Here's link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=14&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwJ4BsD2cAmA3gFDJnIDaA1hBgFzIDOYUoA5gLoPOshsUcA3MQC+xYghwhmyAA6ZcBBumx58yALzIS5ZHAYUA5DBw5DAGmSGARnCiGO50uWsHHzsggM24ALweiwgDy1gBWEAhgAHQ0GIwAFPKqBACUUSZQAKKIABbx8bGWwPgAHimaAHzaHsjAMMiJCmrUtBxRWBB8YDmaGloADOU65AD0I8j4OMjdKMwArjAwoqIpgkA)

Comment: Awesome thanks! I have to parse the payload, but I guess having a 2nd variable isn't too dirty. Will use this